# How img tag gets content over cors headers

Tags: html, image, cors, http-headers

Why, when I use fetch, to load the data from the server with disabled response CORS headers, I'v expectedly got an error:
`Failed to load http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
But image from img tag is presented

```html
<script>
    fetch('http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg').then(console.log);
</script>
<img src="http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg">
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The cross-origin sharing standard does not include `img` tags, but XHR/fetch requests and some cases including drawing images to a canvas does.

> For more info:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS

Comment: But why though??

Comment: You can actually make the img tag and many others respect CORS policy by adding the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute