# Getting origin from browser's img request

Tags: html, http, logging, cors

I am building an API serving images. Those images are loaded from browsers through a classic img tag such as `<img src="myapi.com/random" />`.

This image tag is hosted on different websites using the api. On my server, I'd like to log the origin from which a request is made.

My research so far concludes that img/src attributes are not subject to CORS, so browsers don't add an `origin` header to the request.

Are there any other way for me to know which domain a browser's request is from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978252/how-img-tag-gets-content-over-cors-headers

Comment: yup, your link confirms what I say about CORS and img tags. So we know the browser is not adding a x-cross-origin header to the request. The question then is, is there a way to know where the request is coming from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so someone answered me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/andyhattemer/status/1097847557395496960).

For image tags, a `referer` header is added. I wasn't able to see it because all the requests I've had so far are coming from my own domain, which gets a null referer.